# RegExp works perfectly with .html extension but not with .php extension

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote a script in JavaScript and when I try to run it on a page with .html extension it works perfectly. But when I try to run it on a page with .php I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.CheckStrength
```

This is my code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("password");
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
var check = /[0-9]+$/;

function CheckStrength(){
    if(x.value.length > 7 && x.value.match(check) != null)
        {
            alert("Your password is strong.");
        }
    else if (x.value.length > 3 && x.value.length <= 7)
        {
            alert("Your password strength is medium.");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("Your passwword s**k.");
        }
}
```

Comment: The extension doesn't make a difference, EXCEPT, I'm guessing that the problem is there's no element `x` in the DOM.  OR, you're running this code before the element `x` is rendered (if the script is before the HTML, for example).

Comment: Hi Andaar, this is off topic from your question, but may nullify it completely.  I'd recommend that you look into using zxcvbn for password strength checking.

Comment: @cale_b I know I cannot run this code before <input> and <button> (in my case). This is my php page:
        <article>
            <br>
            <img src="img/haslo.png" alt="haslo.png">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" id="password"> 
            <button id="submit">Check</button>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/password.js"></script>
        </article>

Comment: @Geoff
I'll have an exam in school and I cannot use external libraries or scripts, but thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly within .php extension and I can reproduce that error only when target element does not exists or when javascript inserted *before* the element. Check these;

- check for any typos
- put your script tag before the closing tag of the body element (to make sure target element is available when the script executes)
- wrap your javascript variable definitions in [a window.onload function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: I know this (you have this information in title of the topic), but i want to run this into .php file.

Comment: @Andaar I have already tested it in a .php file, and it works fine unless "#password" is undefined.

Comment: @Andaar Good to know. And would be good to share what was causing the error and how you have fixed it.

Comment: I read first and last point you wrote and of course the middle one is the answer ;)